# Change source address based on destination IP: NAT or routing?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have a router/host with multiple public IP addresses. I want to change the source ip depending on some destination addresses. This has already been asked [here](https://serverfault.com/q/550516/146045):

If the traffic originates from some internal/other host, then the source address has already been selected and we are forced to use NAT, fine.

So we're with local originated traffic. The [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/550576/146045) to the above question suggests, that this only works using appropiate `ip route` entries using `src`.

- Can one create that entry without replicating the default route (which might change for example)?

Another [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/637152/146045) on the contrary says, that NAT also works for local originated traffic.

- Does NAT work for local traffic?
- *IF* it works, is there any recommendations whether NAT or routing should be used? My current thoughts go like this:

  - NAT has the pro, that it handles both local and non-local traffic in one rule (one place to maintain config is good!)
  - NAT has all the cons of NAT.
  - Routing makes things more obvious (and possibly goes into IGP easier).

Comment: Please define: local originated traffic. From what IP pool ? 127.0.0.0/8 ?

Comment: @MichalSokolowski: On the same host, that is running those rules/entries.